# Visual Studio Code CSS Hover Missing on Mac

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css, vscode-extensions

On my Windows machine, I noticed that when I hover my `CSS` class name in a `.jsx` file I'm able to see a hover menu to show me what the actual `CSS` is. However, I'm unable to recreate this on my Macbook Pro. I also don't have this capability for `.html` files.

On my Windows, I have the `HTML CSS Support` extension, but I also have it on my Mac. I tried looking at other suggestions that said to use `CSS Peek` as well, but I installed it and it didn't do anything.

[image: CSS Hover Over]

Here is my Windows VS Code version:

`Version: 1.63.2 (system setup)`

`OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044`

Here is my Mac VS Code version:

`Version: 1.65.2`

`OS: Darwin x64 18.7.0`

Is there an extension I need to install or is there a setting I need to use?

Comment: Have you tried to install the  Tailwind CSS IntelliSense? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss

Answer (score 0):

I had [Tailwind CSS IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss) installed on my Windows machine without realizing it and that did the trick.